# Electrical Circuitry Programs aimed at Children / Beginners

Tags: cad

I'm sorry of this is off topic, but I figured I have a better shot asking the question here then anywhere else.

What I'm looking for is an Electrical Circuity program that was released around 2000 that makes it easy to make circuits on the computer. The program that I am talking about came with a computer mag that I had in England, this was around 2000 or 2001. It allowed you to make a circuit on the computer and test it. It gave you items like light bulbs, switches, batteries and much, much more. I remember being able to over volt light bulbs (with to many batteries) and having them break, so you would have to replace them with a working one. It was very simple and child friendly, I used it for one of my school projects.

Does anyone know of this application, and where I could get it? Or do you have a list of applications like this that you could post here. I will accept applications that are in the same vein, that are better then what I'm asking for. But I would like to emphasize that it should be able to be used by children relativity easily.

Comment: Crocodile Clips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could have been http://www.crocodile-clips.com/ ?

Comment: That is very cool. I'm going to have to look into this one more. But this was not the program I was looking for. *Jedi Mind Tick.*

Comment: After playing with it for a while, this seems close enough to what I wanted to do that this pretty much takes the cake. It is even better then the program I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Snap Circuit](http://www.snapcircuits.net/)s. While that is physical, not a program, being able to build something makes is more "real" and interesting for kids.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: It kinda looked this this but the wires where a red color, not blue, and the 'bread board' was green. And of course it was a computer program.

Answer (score 1):

I know the program the original poster is referring to since I also had played with it and still have an old copy of it with me. It was called "Virtual Labs Electricity". But it has not been in the market for some years, as far as I can tell. It mostly dealt with components like switches, bulbs, batteries, resistors, and fuse. A more recent program with a somewhat similar feel but with many more electronic components is [ElectricVLab](http://www.electricVLab.com).

Comment: Hey look at that, you found it! It was Virtual Labs Electricity!